# Lightning, navigateToURL(), remove special characters

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Instead of whitespace, it adds "%20";
Instead of dollar sign it adds "%24";
How to prevent this?

Comment: URL cannot have white spaces, it breakes the URL

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, expected behavior expected on the Internet and is not specific to Lightning. See [Percent Encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) for more information. "Removing" or "decoding" these values in the URL may have unexpected errors or data loss.